# Conditional formatting question by color gradient. Thanks

Tags: excel

Hi I have about 6000 rows and 20 columns worth of numbers that I want to compare each numbers to each to other within the individual row. Below is a simple example, is there a way where I can do the color gradient conditional formatting for each individual row and then replicate that for the rest of the 6000 rows? If I copy format painter it will do the color gradient over the whole region which is not what I want, I just want the induvial rows. If I highlight the whole region and the color gradient it does the same thing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJFM4.png)

Comment: You need a separate rule for each row. Creation of the rules can be automated with VBA.

Comment: If you don't want to use VBA, then you could use the format painter about 14 times to get 6,000 rows with individual formats. Create rule on row 1, then format painter to row 2. Then double each time (1-2-4-8-16... etc) 14 times to get everything done. Just make sure you don't copy more rows than are formatted and you won't have a problem.